# How to exclude specific sentence not the entire line which contain specific word on it Notepad++ or any Program that could do that

Tags: regex, notepad++

Ok I have a text file like this:

This is the entire article....Fishing vessel crews are almost entirely male, yet women make up a large proportion of workers on the land, mending nets or picking shellfish from sand. ****This is the sentence I want to exclude which contains BBB on it but text goes on without exclude anything else also the specific sentence changes from txt files just the word BBB stay inside it so on each file the sentence will be different..**** Just the  As co-founder of Women In The Food Industry, I was curious as to why this was the case, so asked several women in the seafood market why they felt this pattern has continued into the 21st century and to share their thoughts on how we might improve the visibility of women in the seafood industry.

Comment: In general, this might be hard to swing using regex alone.  The reason for this is that the markers which delimit a sentence (i.e. dot) do not appear just in this context.  Things like abbreviations can also contain dot, which could throw off logic to identify sentences.

Comment: Hi, Virolino just solved the problem below, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, this regex will do the job:

```
([.?!])[^.?!]*?BBB[^.?!]*?[.?!]
```

replace it with

```
\1
```

where `\1` is the punctuation mark ending the previous sentence. Replace `BBB` with the actual keyword.

Test [**here**](https://regex101.com/r/aaBPtD/1).